# How to reduce clickable area of lightning-button?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here is the playground: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/rWl_biVo/edit

**app.html**:

```
<template>
    <lightning-button   variant="brand" 
                        label="Click Me!" 
                        title="Click Me!" 
                        onclick={onBtnClick} 
                        class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-top_small">
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

**app.js**:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
    onBtnClick(evt) {
        console.log('button clicked');
    }
}
```

[image]

How to reduce clickable area of lightning-button? button is aligned in the center of the page but if I click anywhere on that axis, click is getting registered.

If I do the same with plain html button, it is not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slds-align_absolute-center` should be used on the container which contains the element to be centered. Not the element itself.

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
    <lightning-button   variant="brand" 
                    label="Click Me!" 
                    title="Click Me!" 
                    onclick={onBtnClick} 
                    class="slds-m-top_small">
    </lightning-button>
  </div>
</template>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/rWl_biVo/2/edit

You may also want to check out [lightning-layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout/example) for a possibly easier way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Do you know why this weird behavior is only with lightning-button and not with plain html button?

Comment: @javanoob I'm not sure but I think it has to do with how `lightning-button` is rendered in LWC. The component in the inspector looks something like:

<lightning-button class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-top_small">
  <button title="Click Me!" type="button" 
     class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Click Me!</button>
</lightning-button>

`slds-align_absolute-center` overwrites the default inner button behavior to fill the whole 'lightning-button` container, but the click event listener is on `lightning-button` not the inner button, so outside clicks on it still register.